# SQL query from "many to many" table excluding some data with sorting

Tags: sql, join

Good evening, developers!

Few days I'm on one query - maybe you can help me.
I take two tables from my database for example:

PRODUCTS

```
| id | name | type|
| 1  | product-1  | base  |
| 2  | product-1a | modif |
| 3  | product-1b | modif |
| 4  | product-2  | base  |
| 5  | product-2a | modif |
```

PRODUCT_SOURCE

```
| id  | product_id | store_id | quantity | 
|  1  |      2     |     1    |     0    | 
|  2  |      2     |     2    |     5    | 
|  3  |      2     |     3    |     3    | 
|  4  |      3     |     1    |     7    | 
|  5  |      3     |     3    |     0    | 
|  6  |      5     |     3    |     1    |
```

where in the table PRODUCT_SOURCE goes only products with type "modif".
So I need to get all the products from table PRODUCTS
with the quantity form PRODUCT_SOURCE
WITHOUT showing the quantities from other stores (without duplicates) BUT with possibility to sort like shown below:

```
| id |    name    | type  | quantity |
| 3  | product-1b | modif |     7    |
| 2  | product-1a | modif |     0    |
| 6  | product-2a | modif |     0    |
| 1  | product-1  | base  |     -    |
| 4  | product-2  | base  |     -    |
```

I have tried INNER / OUTER JOINs, GROUP BY even tried to put SELECT FROM in ORDER BY clause (I believed it is possible...)

P.S. I have nested query. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT sp.id, sp.name, sp.type, vat.amount, source.shop_id, source.quantity, sp.created_at FROM public."product" sp FULL OUTER JOIN public."product_source" as source on sp.id = source.product_id INNER JOIN public."vat" as vat on sp.vat_id = vat.id WHERE sp.account_id = 1 AND source.shop_id = 1)AS filtered ORDER BY filtered.quantity desc
```

Thank you!
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: If that really your query it must be generating errors, what are they

Comment: there are no errors -  *with LEFT JOIN  - it gives all entries  - from table 1 and table 2 ( that's not what I want, because I need all form table 1 and from table 2 just those with store_id 1 * with WHERE s.store_id=1 gives only those who is in table 2 and has shop_id 1

Comment: ___I have nested query. Something like___ Its alway better to show us the query you really have, not a pseudo query

Comment: How are you running this query?

Comment: SELECT * FROM (SELECT sp.id, sp.name, sp.type, vat.amount, source.shop_id, source.quantity, sp.created_at  
FROM public."product" sp 
FULL OUTER JOIN public."product_source" as source on sp.id = source.product_id
INNER JOIN public."vat" as vat on sp.vat_id = vat.id
WHERE sp.account_id = 1 AND source.shop_id = 1)AS filtered 
ORDER BY filtered.quantity desc

Comment: this one i'm running in pgAdmin, but originally I run it in symfony with raw SQL

Comment: better if you place that in the question. Nobody can read code in a comm link under the questionent. User the [EDIT](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66604992/edit)

Comment: **PGADMIN** you say??? So why have you TAGGED **MYSQL**

Answer (score 1):

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table PRODUCTS  (id int , name varchar(50) , type varchar(50));
insert into PRODUCTS values(1 , 'product-1' , 'base');
insert into PRODUCTS values(2 , 'product-1a' , 'modif');
insert into PRODUCTS values(3 , 'product-1b' , 'modif');
insert into PRODUCTS values(4 , 'product-2' , 'base');
                       
create table PRODUCT_SOURCE( id  int, product_id int , store_id int , quantity int);
insert into PRODUCT_SOURCE values(  1  ,      2     ,     1    ,     0    );
insert into PRODUCT_SOURCE values(  2  ,      2     ,     2    ,     5    );
insert into PRODUCT_SOURCE values(  3  ,      2     ,     3    ,     3    );
insert into PRODUCT_SOURCE values(  4  ,      3     ,     1    ,     7    );
insert into PRODUCT_SOURCE values(  5  ,      3     ,     3    ,     0    );
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select p.id,p.name,p.type,ps.quantity from 
PRODUCTS p left join  PRODUCT_SOURCE ps on p.id=ps.product_id and store_id=1
order by p.id;
```

| id | name | type | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product-1 | base |  |
| 2 | product-1a | modif | 0 |
| 3 | product-1b | modif | 7 |
| 4 | product-2 | base |  |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

If there is store wise product wise multiple row in PRODUCT_SOURCE table then to have sum(quantity) you can use below query:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table PRODUCTS  (id int , name varchar(50) , type varchar(50));
insert into PRODUCTS values(1 , 'product-1' , 'base');
insert into PRODUCTS values(2 , 'product-1a' , 'modif');
insert into PRODUCTS values(3 , 'product-1b' , 'modif');
insert into PRODUCTS values(4 , 'product-2' , 'base');
                       
create table PRODUCT_SOURCE( id  int, product_id int , store_id int , quantity int);
insert into PRODUCT_SOURCE values(  1  ,      2     ,     1    ,     0    );
insert into PRODUCT_SOURCE values(  2  ,      2     ,     2    ,     5    );
insert into PRODUCT_SOURCE values(  3  ,      2     ,     3    ,     3    );
insert into PRODUCT_SOURCE values(  4  ,      3     ,     1    ,     7    );
insert into PRODUCT_SOURCE values(  5  ,      3     ,     3    ,     0    );
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select p.id,p.name,p.type,ps.quantity from 
PRODUCTS p left join 
(select product_id,sum(quantity) quantity 
from PRODUCT_SOURCE ps where store_id=1
group by product_id) ps
on p.id=ps.product_id;
```

| id | name | type | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product-1 | base |  |
| 2 | product-1a | modif | 0 |
| 3 | product-1b | modif | 7 |
| 4 | product-2 | base |  |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: THANK YOU so much!!! that's it - I didn't know that I can use AND just after the JOIN clause. It works perfectly for display the table! 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT sp.id, sp.name, sp.type, vat.amount, source.shop_id, source.quantity, sp.created_at FROM public."product" sp LEFT JOIN public."product_source" as source on sp.id = source.product_id AND source.shop_id = 1 INNER JOIN public."vat" as vat on sp.vat_id = vat.id WHERE sp.account_id = 1)AS filtered ORDER BY filtered.quantity desc

But still - sort by quantity doesn't work good.

Comment: That's great. You did a great job. Your actual query is much more complex than the one in question. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*,
       (select ps.quantity
        from product_source ps
        where ps.product_id = p.id and ps.store_id = 1
       ) as quantity
from products p;
```

If you want this for all stores you can use a `cross join` in the `from` clause:

```
select p.*,
       (select ps.quantity
        from product_source ps
        where ps.product_id = p.id and ps.store_id = s.id
       ) as quantity
from products p cross join
     stores s;
```